# How to decide if call an http request and execute the subscribe body anyways

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, http, asynchronous

I have some code like this:

```
    this.service.callAPI().subscribe(
     data =>  {
              callFunction();
     },
     error => {console.log("Mi mistake")}
    );
```

But I would like to "doubt" if I call *callAPI()*, I mean, I would like to have a chance to check some condition, then decide if I invoke callAPI() and then, despite being called callAPI or not, just execute callFunction(). **BUT**, I don't want to repeat code, I don't want to do this:

```
    if(condition==true){
     this.service.callAPI().subscribe(
       data =>  {
              callFunction();
       },
       error => {console.log("Mi mistake")}
     );
    }
    else{
      callFunction();
    }
```

I was guessing if there is some syntax to allow to express this situation without having to repeat two times the callFunction() code, something semantically like this:

```
    this.service.callAPI().continueIfCondition(condition).subscribe(
     data =>  {
              callFunction();
     },
     error => {console.log("Mi mistake")}
    );
```

which would skip calling the callAPI() method if the condition is met and just proceed to execute the subscribe body. On the contrary, if the condition is false, just wait and do it on the arrival of the response.

Is there any capacity for Observables to behave like this? Am I missing some basic documentation?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [of(true)](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/creation/of) observable:

```
import { of } from 'rxjs';

const callApiIfCondition = () => {
  return condition ? this.service.callAPI() : of(true);
}

callApiIfCondition().subscribe(() => callFunction());
```

Comment: it doesn't execute callFunction() when condition is 'false' , in the actual code is not just a callFunction() but a block o code .. but if I try with just a console.log() it never get executed.

Comment: Yes, I'm wrong. Empty never calls obaervable next, only complete. See the updated answer